# is it possible to aggregate Azure resources from different subscriptions?

Tags: azure

Our team has *Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Premium* subscriptions for all our devs. I have been taking advantage of the $100 per month allowance and am building more infrastructure in the cloud.

However, I would like other members of our team to access certain of the assets. I am quite new to the Azure infrastructure, so this might be a dumb question. **But can they access my blobs? and can I control exactly who can access my blobs?**

They can obviously RDP into my VMs, that's not an issue. I assume they can hit my VMs too, via the IP address, inside Azure, etc. However, I am more interested in the Blobs. Mostly because I am starting to upload a lot of utility data (large sample datasets, common software we all install, etc.) and I would like to avoid all of us having to upload all of it again for each subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

- As of today (11/8/2013), you cannot "pool" MSDN resources meaning..have 4 subscriptions add up to $400/month and do ala carte cloud services
- You can have one admin/or several for multiple subscriptions, this will allow you to view the different subscriptions in the portal and manage them in a single spot
- You can also have different deployment profiles, so one Visual Studio instance can deploy to different Azure accounts.

Specific to your question, you have blob access keys and if you share the name of the storage account and key...yes they can access your data located there.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to control access to your blobs by using SAS (Shared Access Signatures)

SAS grants granular access to container, blob, table, & queue

This should be a good resource to start with :

[Manage Access to Windows Azure Storage Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee393343.aspx)

[Create and Use a Shared Access Signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj721951.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> However, I would like other members of our team to access certain of
>   the assets. I am quite new to the Azure infrastructure, so this might
>   be a dumb question. But can they access my blobs? and can I control
>   exactly who can access my blobs?

To answer specifically this question, Yes your team members can access the data stored in any blob storage account in any of your subscription. There are two ways by which you can provide them access to blob storage:

1. By giving them account name/account key: Using this, they get full access to storage account and essentially become owners of that storage account.
2. By using Shared Access Signature: If you want to give them restricted access to blob storage, you would need to use SAS as described by Dan Dinu. SAS basically gives you a URL using which users in possession of that URL can explore storage (by writing some code), however it is not possible to identify which user accessed which storage. For that you would need to write something on your own.